# Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property

Tags: java, sorting, date, comparator

I read about sorting ArrayLists using a Comparator but in all of the examples people used `compareTo` which according to some research is a method for Strings.

I wanted to sort an ArrayList of custom objects by one of their properties: a Date object
(`getStartDay()`). Normally I compare them by `item1.getStartDate().before(item2.getStartDate())` so I was wondering whether I could write something like:

```
public class CustomComparator {
    public boolean compare(Object object1, Object object2) {
        return object1.getStartDate().before(object2.getStartDate());
    }
}

public class RandomName {
    ...
    Collections.sort(Database.arrayList, new CustomComparator);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts

Comment: [Answer by @Yishai in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421322/how-do-i-sort-a-list-with-multiple-sort-parameters#1421537) demonstrates elegant use of enum for custom sorting and grouped  sorting (multiple arguments) utilizing comparator chaining.

Answer (score 1722, accepted):

Since [`Date`](//docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) implements [`Comparable`](//docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), it has a `compareTo` method just like `String` does.

So your custom [`Comparator`](//docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) could look like this:

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<MyObject> {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        return o1.getStartDate().compareTo(o2.getStartDate());
    }
}
```

The `compare()` method must return an `int`, so you couldn't directly return a `boolean` like you were planning to anyway.

Your sorting code would be just about like you wrote:

```
Collections.sort(Database.arrayList, new CustomComparator());
```

A slightly shorter way to write all this, if you don't need to reuse your comparator, is to write it as an inline anonymous class:

```
Collections.sort(Database.arrayList, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        return o1.getStartDate().compareTo(o2.getStartDate());
    }
});
```

---

## Since [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

You can now write the last example in a shorter form by using a [lambda expression](//docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) for the `Comparator`:

```
Collections.sort(Database.arrayList, 
                        (o1, o2) -> o1.getStartDate().compareTo(o2.getStartDate()));
```

And `List` has a [`sort(Comparator)`](//docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) method, so you can shorten this even further:

```
Database.arrayList.sort((o1, o2) -> o1.getStartDate().compareTo(o2.getStartDate()));
```

This is such a common idiom that there's [a built-in method](//docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) to generate a `Comparator` for a class with a `Comparable` key:

```
Database.arrayList.sort(Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getStartDate));
```

All of these are equivalent forms.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that it should return `int` and that you'd better to use `Date#compareTo()` for this. Why this isn't upvoted above the other answer is beyond me. This link may also be useful: [Object Ordering Tutorial at Sun.com](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html).

Comment: I think the answer best should also include the proper way to do it in Java 8.
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getStartDate)); which reads better and is less error prone. It's very easy to write return o1.getStartDate().compareTo(o1.getStartDate());

Comment: you can use to compare int values like this
"return o1.getDistance()-o2.getDistance();"

Comment: what happens when `o1.getStartDate()` returns null?

Comment: @Taylor O'Connor: it throws a NullPointerException.

Comment: @Kuba better yet, use `List.sort()`.

Comment: The order of String sort is asc by default when use `s1.compareTo(s2)` and desc when use `s2.compareTo(s1)`

Comment: If you are using Java 8, see if you can get rid of `Date` in favour of one of the new and more programmer frindly classes in the `java.time` package.

Comment: This solution does not work on Android API <24. Do you guys know a solution for this?

Comment: In case anyone is looking at this because they're on Android API <24, you can use `Collections.sort()` to sort your lists.

Comment: Nowadays you can use:

`Collections.sort(Database.arrayList, Comparator.comparing(Object::method));`

Comment: @JFreeman: Thanks for commenting! I didn't include that version because it's nearly identical to the last version I posted, only a little longer to type.

Comment: There's a missing, yet extremely important detail: in what order does .compareTo() work? Ascending? Descending?

Comment: Is there no general method that simply allows nulls and has options to consider them at the front or end of the sorting? You'd think something like `Integer.compare` would offer this, but its args are `int`, not `Integer`.

Comment: @Nyerguds: You can wrap `Comparator.naturalOrder()` inside either `Comparator.nullsFirst()` or `Comparator.nullsLast()` to achieve this effect with any class that implements `Comparable`, which `Integer` does.

Answer (score 201):

Classes that has a natural sort order (a class Number, as an example) should implement the Comparable interface, whilst classes that has no natural sort order (a class Chair, as an example) should be provided with a Comparator (or an anonymous Comparator class).

Two examples:

```
public class Number implements Comparable<Number> {
    private int value;

    public Number(int value) { this.value = value; }
    public int compareTo(Number anotherInstance) {
        return this.value - anotherInstance.value;
    }
}

public class Chair {
    private int weight;
    private int height;

    public Chair(int weight, int height) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.height = height;
    }
    /* Omitting getters and setters */
}
class ChairWeightComparator implements Comparator<Chair> {
    public int compare(Chair chair1, Chair chair2) {
        return chair1.getWeight() - chair2.getWeight();
    }
}
class ChairHeightComparator implements Comparator<Chair> {
    public int compare(Chair chair1, Chair chair2) {
        return chair1.getHeight() - chair2.getHeight();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();
...
Collections.sort(numbers);

List<Chair> chairs = new ArrayList<Chair>();
// Sort by weight:
Collections.sort(chairs, new ChairWeightComparator());
// Sort by height:
Collections.sort(chairs, new ChairHeightComparator());

// You can also create anonymous comparators;
// Sort by color:
Collections.sort(chairs, new Comparator<Chair>() {
    public int compare(Chair chair1, Chair chair2) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried that - but when I want to access the comparator class ChairWeightComparator outside in any other class I do not get access to this class (of course not since its not public). Do I need to create a new public ChairWeightComparator class in a separate file? - am I really the first one to try this after 3 years or did I miss sth?

Comment: @user387184 - simply make it public, and put it in it's own file (preferably it's own package as well) and you'll be able to use it everywhere in you project. No need to create an additional class!

Comment: you mean create a new file - not a class and put in the code: "class ChairWeightComparator implements Comparator<Chair> {...." ?

Comment: @user387184, exactly - but with the key word `public` in front of `class`.

Comment: This is not working on my Laptop. It shows int cannot be dereferenced error.  How to correct it ?

Answer (score 164):

For sorting an `ArrayList` you could use the following code snippet:

```
Collections.sort(studList, new Comparator<Student>(){
    public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
        return s1.getFirstName().compareToIgnoreCase(s2.getFirstName());
    }
});
```

Comment: Anybody using lambda http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property/25686715#25686715

Comment: That sorts but gives double value for each element

Comment: This is not working on my Laptop. It shows int cannot be dereferenced error.  How to correct it ?

Answer (score 47):

### JAVA 8 lambda expression

```
Collections.sort(studList, (Student s1, Student s2) ->{
        return s1.getFirstName().compareToIgnoreCase(s2.getFirstName());
});
```

#### OR

```
Comparator<Student> c = (s1, s2) -> s1.firstName.compareTo(s2.firstName);
studList.sort(c)
```

Comment: Or `Collections.sort(studList, Comparator.comparing(Student::getFirstName));`

Comment: .. or `studList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Student::getFirstName));`

Comment: The sort order will always be ascending in your case. I've take care of sort order too in my example. Thanks Gentlemen.

Answer (score 45):

Yes, you can.  There are two options with comparing items, the [Comparable](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, and the [Comparator](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface.

Both of these interfaces allow for different behavior.  Comparable allows you to make the object act like you just described Strings (in fact, String implements Comparable).  The second, Comparator, allows you to do what you are asking to do.  You would do it like this:

```
Collections.sort(myArrayList, new MyComparator());
```

That will cause the Collections.sort method to use your comparator for it's sorting mechanism.  If the objects in the ArrayList implement comparable, you can instead do something like this:

```
Collections.sort(myArrayList);
```

The [Collections](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class contains a number of these useful, common tools.

Comment: This is not working on my Laptop. It shows int cannot be dereferenced error.  How to correct it ?

Answer (score 39):

With Java 8 you can use a method reference for your comparator:

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;

Collections.sort(list, comparing(MyObject::getStartDate));
```

Comment: @user387184 unfortunately android does not support Java 8, although there may be a [workaround](http://zserge.com/blog/android-lambda.html) (I haven't tested it).

Answer (score 15):

Since technologies appear everyday, the answer will change in the time. I took a look at LambdaJ and seems very interesting.

You can try solving these tasks with **LambdaJ**. You can find it here: http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/

Here you have an example:

**Sort Iterative**

```
List<Person> sortedByAgePersons = new ArrayList<Person>(persons);
Collections.sort(sortedByAgePersons, new Comparator<Person>() {
        public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
           return Integer.valueOf(p1.getAge()).compareTo(p2.getAge());
        }
});
```

**Sort with lambda**

```
List<Person> sortedByAgePersons = sort(persons, on(Person.class).getAge());
```

Of course, having this kind of beauty impacts in the performance (an average of 2 times), but can you find a more readable code?

Comment: That sorts but gives double value for each element how to avoid it

Comment: @Sam, it shouldn't... it's working as expected. Unless you are using a new version with a bug, which I recommend you to post it in the forum. Anyway, this answer was post prior to java 8, if you use it, then it will much better than using lambdaj

Comment: I had to remove even items in a foreach loop other wise it gives me double of each content.

Answer (score 13):

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;

public class test {

public static class Person {
    public String name;
    public int id;
    public Date hireDate;

    public Person(String iname, int iid, Date ihireDate) {
        name = iname;
        id = iid;
        hireDate = ihireDate;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + id + " " + hireDate.toString();
    }

    // Comparator
    public static class CompId implements Comparator<Person> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Person arg0, Person arg1) {
            return arg0.id - arg1.id;
        }
    }

    public static class CompDate implements Comparator<Person> {
        private int mod = 1;
        public CompDate(boolean desc) {
            if (desc) mod =-1;
        }
        @Override
        public int compare(Person arg0, Person arg1) {
            return mod*arg0.hireDate.compareTo(arg1.hireDate);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm-dd-yyyy");
    ArrayList<Person> people;
    people = new ArrayList<Person>();
    try {
        people.add(new Person("Joe", 92422, df.parse("12-12-2010")));
        people.add(new Person("Joef", 24122, df.parse("1-12-2010")));
        people.add(new Person("Joee", 24922, df.parse("12-2-2010")));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Collections.sort(people, new Person.CompId());
    System.out.println("BY ID");
    for (Person p : people) {
        System.out.println(p.toString());
    }

    Collections.sort(people, new Person.CompDate(false));
    System.out.println("BY Date asc");
    for (Person p : people) {
        System.out.println(p.toString());
    }
    Collections.sort(people, new Person.CompDate(true));
    System.out.println("BY Date desc");
    for (Person p : people) {
        System.out.println(p.toString());
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This question was answered some time ago. Before resurrecting old threads, please be sure your response adds something significant to the thread.

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer.

Comment: Just compile and run.  The code is the comment and explanation.

Answer (score 13):

## Function & method reference

The [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,java.util.Comparator)) method can sort a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) using a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) you pass. That `Comparator` can be implemented using the [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function)) method where you can pass a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) as the necessary [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html). Fortunately, the actual code is much simpler and shorter than this description.

For Java 8:

```
Collections.sort(list, comparing(ClassName::getName));
```

or

```
Collections.sort(list, comparing(ClassName::getName).reversed());
```

Another way is

```
Collections.sort(list, comparing(ClassName::getName, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```

Comment: Call requires API level 24

Answer (score 10):

Best easy way with JAVA 8 is for English Alphabetic sort

**Class Implementation**

```
public class NewspaperClass implements Comparable<NewspaperClass>{
   public String name;

   @Override
   public int compareTo(NewspaperClass another) {
      return name.compareTo(another.name);
   }
}
```

**Sort**

```
  Collections.sort(Your List);
```

If you want to sort for alphabet that contains non English characters you can use Locale... Below code use Turkish character sort...

**Class Implementation**

```
public class NewspaperClass implements Comparator<NewspaperClass> {
   public String name;
   public Boolean isUserNewspaper=false;
   private Collator trCollator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("tr_TR"));



   @Override
   public int compare(NewspaperClass lhs, NewspaperClass rhs) {
      trCollator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
      return trCollator.compare(lhs.name,rhs.name);
   }
}
```

**Sort**

```
Collections.sort(your array list,new NewspaperClass());
```

Answer (score 7):

**You can Sort using  java 8**

```
yourList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Classname::getName));

or

yourList.stream().forEach(a -> a.getBObjects().sort(Comparator.comparing(Classname::getValue)));
```

Answer (score 6):

Java 8 Lambda shortens the sort.

```
Collections.sort(stdList, (o1, o2) -> o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName()));
```

Comment: `Collections.sort(stdList, Comparator.comparing(SomeClass::getName));`

Answer (score 6):

From `Java 8` and onward we don't have to use `Collections.sort()` directly. `List` interface has a default `sort()` method:

```
List<User> users = Arrays.asList(user1,user2,user3);
users.sort( (u1, u2) -> { 
return u1.getFirstName.compareTo(u2.getFirstName());});
```

See http://visvv.blogspot.in/2016/01/sorting-objects-in-java-8.html.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Bean Comparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/bean-comparator/) to sort on any property in your custom class.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that's possible for instance  in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784218/get-indexes-of-n-smallest-elements-in-an-array/2784353#2784353) I sort by the property `v` of the class `IndexValue`

```
    // Sorting by property v using a custom comparator.
    Arrays.sort( array, new Comparator<IndexValue>(){
        public int compare( IndexValue a, IndexValue b ){
            return a.v - b.v;
        }
    });
```

If you notice here I'm creating a *anonymous inner class* ( which is the Java for closures ) and passing it directly to the `sort` method of the class `Arrays`

Your object may also implement `Comparable` ( that's what String and most of the core libraries in Java does ) but that would define the "natural sort order" of the class it self, and doesn't let you plug new ones.

Comment: ...but which you can just override with `Comparator` :)

Answer (score 5):

I found most if not all of these answers rely on the underlying class (Object) to implement comparable or to have a helper comparable interface.

Not with my solution! The following code lets you compare object's field by knowing their string name. You could easily modify it not to use the name, but then you need to expose it or construct one of the Objects you want to compare against.

```
Collections.sort(anArrayListOfSomeObjectPerhapsUsersOrSomething, new ReflectiveComparator(). new ListComparator("name"));

public class ReflectiveComparator {
    public class FieldComparator implements Comparator<Object> {
        private String fieldName;

        public FieldComparator(String fieldName){
            this.fieldName = fieldName;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
        @Override
        public int compare(Object object1, Object object2) {
            try {
                Field field = object1.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
                field.setAccessible(true);

                Comparable object1FieldValue = (Comparable) field.get(object1);
                Comparable object2FieldValue = (Comparable) field.get(object2);

                return object1FieldValue.compareTo(object2FieldValue);
            }catch (Exception e){}

            return 0;
        }
    }

    public class ListComparator implements Comparator<Object> {
        private String fieldName;

        public ListComparator(String fieldName) {
            this.fieldName = fieldName;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
        @Override
        public int compare(Object object1, Object object2) {
            try {
                Field field = object1.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Comparable o1FieldValue = (Comparable) field.get(object1);
                Comparable o2FieldValue = (Comparable) field.get(object2);

                if (o1FieldValue == null){ return -1;}
                if (o2FieldValue == null){ return 1;}
                return o1FieldValue.compareTo(o2FieldValue);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Field doesn't exist", e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Field inaccessible", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try Guava [Ordering](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html):

```
Function<Item, Date> getStartDate = new Function<Item, Date>() {
    public Date apply(Item item) {
        return item.getStartDate();
    }
};

List<Item> orderedItems = Ordering.natural().onResultOf(getStartDate).
                          sortedCopy(items);
```

Answer (score 5):

Well if you using Java 8 or older version Here is the Best solution.

```
Collections.sort(studentList, Comparator.comparing(Student::getCgpa).reversed().thenComparing(Student:: getFname).thenComparing(Student::getId));
```

In this case, it will first sort with 'getCgpa' first and for the second part it will sort with getFname and getId.  Which is field into the pojo class.

Comment: That is java 8 or newer, not java8 or older.

Answer (score 3):

your customComparator class must implement java.util.Comparator in order to be used.
it must also overide compare() AND equals()

compare() must answer the question:  Is object 1 less than, equal to or greater than object 2?

full docs: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Answer (score 3):

This code snippets might be useful. If you want to sort an Object
in my case I want to sort by VolumeName:

```
public List<Volume> getSortedVolumes() throws SystemException {
    List<Volume> volumes = VolumeLocalServiceUtil.getAllVolumes();
    Collections.sort(volumes, new Comparator<Volume>() {
        public int compare(Volume o1, Volume o2) {
            Volume p1 = (Volume) o1;
            Volume p2 = (Volume) o2;
            return p1.getVolumeName().compareToIgnoreCase(
                    p2.getVolumeName());
        }
    });
    return volumes;
}
```

This works. I use it in my jsp.

Answer (score 3):

With this library [here](https://github.com/ipillars/public/tree/master/java/utils/com/ipillars/sorter) you can sort the list of custom objects on multiple columns. The library uses version 8.0 features. Sample is also available there. Here is a sample to do

```
SortKeys sortKeys = new SortKeys();
sortKeys.addField("firstName")
            .addField("age", true); // This (true) will sort the age descending

// Other ways to specify a property to the sorter are
//      .addField("lastName", String.class);
//      .addField("dob", Date.class, true);

// Instantiate a ListSorter
ListSorter listSorter = new ListSorter();

// Pass the data to sort (listToSort) and the "by keys" to sort (sortKeys)
List sortedList = (List<Person>) listSorter.sortList(listToSort, sortKeys);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look into this [presentation](http://2016.java-forum-stuttgart.de/_data/D4_Wiedeking.pdf) hold at the Java Forum in Stuttgart Germany in 2016.

Only a few slides use German language, 99% of the content is "English based" Java source code; like

```
someCollection.sort(
  OurCustomComparator
    .comparing(Person::getName)
    .thenComparing(Person::getId)
);
```

where `OurCustomComparator` is using default methods (and other interesting ideas). As shown, leading to very concise code to pick some getter method for sorting; and super simple chaining (or reversing) of sort criteria.

If you are into java8, you find a lot of material there to get you started.

Comment: fyi, presentation link is dead.

Comment: @AJW Thanks, yeah, there is a reason why I added the code here ... I assumed that the link would break one day. Just no clue where else I could provide that file from .

Answer (score 3):

New since 1.8 is a List.sort() method instead of using the Collection.sort()
so you directly call  mylistcontainer.sort()

Here is a code snippet which demonstrates the List.sort() feature:

```
List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
fruits.add(new Fruit("Kiwi","green",40));
fruits.add(new Fruit("Banana","yellow",100));
fruits.add(new Fruit("Apple","mixed green,red",120));
fruits.add(new Fruit("Cherry","red",10));

// a) using an existing compareto() method
fruits.sort((Fruit f1,Fruit f2) -> f1.getFruitName().compareTo(f2.getFruitName()));
System.out.println("Using String.compareTo(): " + fruits);
//Using String.compareTo(): [Apple is: mixed green,red, Banana is: yellow, Cherry is: red, Kiwi is: green]

// b) Using a comparable class
fruits.sort((Fruit f1,Fruit f2) -> f1.compareTo(f2));  
System.out.println("Using a Comparable Fruit class (sort by color): " + fruits);
// Using a Comparable Fruit class (sort by color): [Kiwi is green, Apple is: mixed green,red, Cherry is: red, Banana is: yellow]
```

The Fruit class is:

```
public class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit>
{
    private String name;
    private String color;
    private int quantity;

    public Fruit(String name,String color,int quantity)
    { this.name = name; this.color = color; this.quantity = quantity; }

    public String getFruitName() { return name; }        
    public String getColor() { return color; }  
    public int getQuantity() { return quantity; }

    @Override public final int compareTo(Fruit f) // sorting the color
    {
        return this.color.compareTo(f.color);
    }     
    @Override public String toString()
    {   
        return (name + " is: " + color);
    }
} // end of Fruit class
```

Answer (score 2):

using the java-8 stream api you can sort an `ArrayList` by:

```
 Comparator<Person> birthdayComparator = Comparator.comparing(Person::getBirthday);
 List<Person> sortedList = list.stream().sorted(birthdayComparator).collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this process:

```
public class SortUtil
{    
    public static <T> List<T> sort(List<T> list, String sortByProperty)
    {
            Collections.sort(list, new BeanComparator(sortByProperty));
            return list;
    }
}

List<T> sortedList = SortUtil<T>.sort(unsortedList, "startDate");
```

If you list of objects has a property called `startDate`, you call use this over and over.  You can even chain them `startDate.time`.

This requires your object to be `Comparable` which means you need a `compareTo`, `equals`, and `hashCode` implementation.

Yes, it could be faster... But now you don't have to make a new Comparator for each type of sort.  If you can save on dev time and give up on runtime, you might go with this one.

Comment: 1, this answer was given 2 hours earlier with working code provided as well. There is no need to repost the same solution and clutter the forum especially since BeanComparator is not a standard class, so its not really a solution if the poster doesn't know what you are talking about. If you like the original suggestion you can upvote it and add a comment if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 use can define the `Comparator` in one line using `Comparator.comparing()`

Use any of the following way:

**Option 1:**

```
listToBeSorted.sort(Comparator.comparing(CustomObject::getStartDate));
```

**Option 2:**

```
Collections.sort(listToBeSorted, Comparator.comparing(CustomObject::getStartDate));
```

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34279142/642706) from 3 years prior.

Comment: Not exactly, only option 2 here is similar to option 1 in the mentioned answer. I feel two different answers can have atleast some similarities if they are answer to the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom class can implement the "Comparable" interface, which requires an implementation of the CompareTo method. In the CompareTo method, you can then define what it means that an object is *less than or more than* the other object. So in your example, it can look something like this:

```
public class MyCustomClass implements Comparable<MyCustomClass>{
```

..........

```
 @Override
public int compareTo(MyCustomClass a) {
    if(this.getStartDate().before(a.getStartDate())){
        return -1;
    }else if(a.getStartDate().before(this.getStartDate())){
        return 1;
    }else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

A negative number indicates that **this** is smaller than the object being compared to. A positive number indicates that **this** is larger than the compared to object and a Zero means that the objects are equal.

You can then use the collections.sort(myList) to sort your list without having to feed in a comparator. This method also has the advantage of having things sorted automatically if you use a sorted collection data structures like a TreeSet or a TreeMap.

You can check this article if you would like to read more about the Comparable interface (disclosure: I am the author ;) )
https://nullbeans.com/the-java-comparable-interface-automatic-sort-of-collections/

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Springs [PropertyComparator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/support/PropertyComparator.html) if you have just a String property path to the (nested) property you want to sort:

```
List<SomeObject> list = ...;
PropertyComparator<HitWithInfo> propertyComparator = new PropertyComparator<>(
    "property.nested.myProperty", false, true);
list.sort(propertyComparator);
```

The drawback is, that this comparator silently ignores properties which does not exist or are not accessible and handles this as *null* value for comparison. This means, you should carefully test such a comparator or validate the existence of the property path somehow.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried lots of different solutions available on internet but solution which works for me is available at below link.

https://www.java67.com/2017/07/how-to-sort-arraylist-of-objects-using.html

Comment: Please provide a answer here instead of  providing link . Links can be broken thus making your answer useless