# Priority queue for HashMaps

Tags: java

I have a hash map of a string and a vertex which is a class.

I want to create a priority queue for an attribute distance of vertex class... How should I do it...

```
private final PriorityQueue Nodes ;
private HashMap<String,Vertex> c ;
```

I have to create a priority queue on all the members of the hashmap c according to the vertex.distance value.....

Please tell how should i do that as I always get compilation error on whatever I am trying....

Comment: I am trying to get a priority queue which handles the vertex distances... As I have stored the vertices in hashmap I need to get this...

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683041/java-how-do-i-use-a-priorityqueue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing your implementation, I give the following answer:

Looking at [the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html), it appears that there is a constructor which accepts a [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).  I suspect that what you need to do is create a comparator which corresponds to the vertex.distance value.

So, for example (this is untested code.  Treat it as pseudo code):

```
class VertexComparator implements Comparator<Vertex>{
  public int compare(Vertex v1, Vertex v2){
    return v1.distance - v2.distance;
  }
}
```

After that create the `Nodes` like:

```
PriorityQueue Nodes = new PriorityQueue(100, new VertexComparator());
```

Comment: Just a question .... Where will I be using the hashmap in this ... as in inside the comparator function or just for passing inside the VertexComparator function....

Comment: I'd get each vertex in the HashMap, and put the it in the Nodes PQ.  But, it is hard for me to know because I do not know the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your question I think you want a `PriorityQueue<Vertex>`, which sorts instances of the `Vertex` class according to the value of its `distance` attribute.

What you need is to either define a `Comparator` that you pass in to the `PriorityQueue` which specifies how the objects are ordered, or you could make your `Vertex` class implement `Comparable<Vertex>` and implement its `compareTo` method.