# Question about java priority queues

Tags: java, priority-queue

I'm trying to have a queue that can take objects of type X. Each of these object X have a variable of type int called distance. How do I make a priority queue that takes object of type X but sorts them based on each object's variable distance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How do I use a PriorityQueue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683041/java-how-do-i-use-a-priorityqueue)

Answer (score 2):

[PriorityQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) provides a [constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue%28int,%20java.util.Comparator%29) that takes a [comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).  You can use this to order the items.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following comparator:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class XComparator implements Comparator<X>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(X m, X n)
    {

        if (m.distance < n.distance)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (m.distance > n.distance)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Here's how you would create the priority queue:

```
int initialCapacity = 20;
Comparator<X> comparator = new XComparator();
PriorityQueue<X> queue = new PriorityQueue<X>(initialCapacity, comparator);
```

Answer (score 0):

Homework much?

Have a look at the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).

In short, you can implement a priority queue with a heap.