# PriorityQueue not sorting on add

Tags: java, sorting, priority-queue

I have a Priority Queue in which I add a Node object to, where the Nodes should be sorted by a value that they contain.  For some reason, the priority queue will not sort the Nodes on add. If anyone can see something wrong with this or has any guidance, I appreciate it. Here is a brief example:

```
PriorityQueue<Node> PQ = new PriorityQueue<Node>();
        //for each entry create a node and add it to the PriorityQueue
        for(Entry<Character,Integer> entry : entries){
            PQ.add(new Node(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue(), true));
        }
```

here is the node's `compareTo` method:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Node n) {
  if(n.frequency.intValue() > this.frequency.intValue()) return  -1;
  else if(n.frequency.intValue() == this.frequency.intValue()) return 0;
  else return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I guess you expect `PriorityQueue` to return elements in particular order when you iterate it. However, `PriorityQueue` doesn't provide such a behaviour, because it's implemented as a priority heap rather than sorted list. From [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).

The only guarantee provided by `PriorityQueue` is that `poll()`, `peek()`, etc return the least element. If you need ordered iteration of elements, use some other collection such as `TreeSet`.

Comment: Right, but I expect it to be sorted on removal of each object using the remove() method

Comment: @Trevor: You haven't shown the iteration code. Please update your question to show a show but *complete* example, that we can compile and run.

Comment: Nevermind, I realize now that on remove() the object are sorted.  Thanks all

Comment: Oh wow, really? And here I thought I had the perfect class for the purpose. :(

Answer (score 9):

For anyone looking how to iterate the queue following the order, this can be achieved by using [poll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#poll()) or [remove](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractQueue.html#remove()).

```java
while (!queue.isEmpty())
    System.out.println(queue.poll());

while (!queue.isEmpty())
    System.out.println(queue.remove());
```

The only diference between `poll()` and `remove()`, is that poll returns null when is empty and remove throws a `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: the foreach loop doesn't view the items according to the priority however polling clears the doubt.