# Priority Queue with overrided comparator

Tags: java, priority-queue

I'm using PriorityQueue in Java.

I have an object with this structure:

```
public class CostObject {

  String value;
  double cost;

  public CostObject(String val, double cst) {
    value = val;
    cost = cst;
  }
}
```

The priority is the cost from cheapest to most expensive:

```
PriorityQueue<CostObject> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(1, new Comparator<CostObject> () {

    @Override
    public int compare(CostObject co1, CostObject co2) {
            return (co1.cost > co2.cost) ? 1 : -1;
    }

});
```

I use add to include objects in the queue.

```
CostObject co = new CostObject("test", cost);
queue.add(co);
```

It works for every element in the queue but the last one I add, that is always in the bottom position.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would suggest to look also at this answer regarding the PriorityQueue's iterator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695017/priorityqueue-not-sorting-on-add. If you use it to print the results (or use PriorityQueue.toString), they won't be in a sorted order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The priority queue will only guarantee that the head is the cheapest (or smallest/biggest depending on the comparator), but not guarantee on the overall order.
if you do `queue.poll()` to **retrieve** and **remove** the head, you will get the elements in order, since every time you poll the current head, the priority queue will make sure the new head is the cheapest element

Answer (score 6):

Your comparator can never return 0. This violates at least one of the rules in `Comparator.compare`'s general contract, namely:

```
sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))
```

If `x` and `y` have the same cost, both `compare(x, y)` and `compare(y, x)` will be -1.

You should use `Double.compare`, or `Comparator.comparingDouble` to correctly implement `Comparator`:

```
new PriorityQueue<>(1, new Comparator<>() {
    public int compare(CostObject co1, CostObject co2) {
        return Double.compare(co1.cost, co2.cost);
    }
});
```

Or:

```
new PriorityQueue<>(1, Comparator.comparingDouble(CostObject::getCost));
```

---

As mentioned by Slimu in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64764607/priority-queue-with-overrided-comparator/64764738#comment114510616_64764607), you might be getting elements out of the queue using its `iterator` (such as with a for loop). This is not guaranteed to give you the elements in the right order, which is possibly why "but the last one I add, that is always in the bottom position". You should `poll` from the queue if you want the elements in the right order.

Comment: i dont understand why but this is not working, if I check the queue, the order is the pushed one

Comment: @cucuru _How_ did you "check the queue"? Did you use a for loop by any chance? You should `poll` from it instead.