# Collections -ArrayList

Tags: java, collections

I have a arraylist and it contains a 100 employee object and each object contains "Name" and "Salary". We need to find the Max salaried employeee from the Object .Please let me know what is the way .

I thought of implementing compareTo and equals Method is it right , and also using Collections.sort Is it the right way or is there any other way

Comment: In what language / platform?

Comment: Your questions are starting to sound very homework-y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the language is Java, then either implement the [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface (just `compareTo`--no need for `equals`) for the objects in the array list and call `Collections.sort(arraylist)`, or else write a [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and call `Collections.sort(arraylist, comparator)`. The latter is more flexible, as it doesn't require your objects to always be sorted by salary.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention The language is java

Answer (score 0):

You need not do the sorting yourself. Your case is perfect for priority queues. Write a comparator as @Ted suggested and add the data to PriorityQueue - it'll give you the min or max based on the data you want the min/max of - salary in your case. Details in this post:
[How do I use a PriorityQueue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683041/java-how-do-i-use-a-priorityqueue)