# Java Help : PriorityQueue

Tags: java, priority-queue

I have a class called jobType

```
package pcs_assignment_2;

public class JobType
{
    private int ID;
    private double aTime;
    private double sTime;

    public JobType(int ID, double aTime, double sTime)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.aTime = aTime;
        this.sTime = sTime;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public double getaTime() {
        return aTime;
    }

    public void setaTime(double aTime) {
        this.aTime = aTime;
    }

    public double getsTime() {
        return sTime;
    }

    public void setsTime(double sTime) {
        this.sTime = sTime;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "JobType{" + "ID=" + ID + "aTime=" + aTime + "sTime=" + sTime + '}';
    }

}
```

Now what I wanna have is a PriorityQue of Type JobType which sorts the queue on the basis of sTime. Is it possible?

Comment: What part of the JavaDocs for [PriorityQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) are you having problems understanding?

Comment: using the comparator....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How do I use a PriorityQueue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683041/java-how-do-i-use-a-priorityqueue) - that has a concrete example of using PriorityQueue with a Comparator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A custom comparator needs to be written, see the code below.
here 10 in the initial capacity of the queue.

```
    new PriorityQueue<JobType>(10, new Comparator<JobType>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(JobType o1, JobType o2) {
             return Double.compare(o1.sTime,o2.sTime); 
    }
    });
```

Comment: Would the capacity of the que keep increasing as and when objects get added ??

Comment: Yes, it would. Its just an initial capacity, there is no constructor for only comparator.

Comment: Creating a `Double` for every comparison is expensive. An alternative is to use `Double.compare(o1.sTime, o2.sTime)`

Comment: Good comment!, made the change

Comment: @Peter why do you say that creating `Double` for every comparison is expensive? Because of the object creation overhead?

Comment: @Hemal Pandya, Yes. It can be 10-100x longer than the comparison itself and creates a lot of garbage if called enough. Note: two objects get created. (the second is auto-boxed)

Comment: @Peter This is an interesting contention. Looking at the code of `Double.compare` it seems that the comparison itself would be quite expensive. Moreover, I believe object creation is cheap and the GC overhead also should be very small for short lived objects. Just to learn, I will ask this question to the community.

Comment: Using an object or not can make a big difference in a micro-benchmark. However I tried comparing what you get in this type of situation, with a PriorityQueue and and object wrapper and the difference is much smaller overall. Using the primitive method was about 15% faster for the whole test.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I guess the actual difference will vary depending on the overall usage and make come down ever more in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `PriorityQueue` with a `Comparator`. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue(int,%20java.util.Comparator)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the comparator option, I believe it would be possible to achieve the same behavior by just making your class implement the Comparable interface; do so only if this ordering mimics the natural ordering of your object.

Answer (score -1):

You could have a simple List  where all the jobs reside in and then before you want to take one out, sort the list using a compare function on the sTime.