# Change priorityQueue to max priorityqueue

Tags: java, collections, priority-queue

I have priority queue in Java of Integers:

```
 PriorityQueue<Integer> pq= new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
```

When I call `pq.poll()` I get the minimum element.

Question: how to change the code to get the maximum element?

Comment: I think you should use the constructor that receives a comparator for that. Use the Collections.reverseOrder to obtain a reversed comparator.

Comment: you need to pass a comparator. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683041/java-how-do-i-use-a-priorityqueue

Answer (score 311, accepted):

How about like this:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(10, Collections.reverseOrder());
queue.offer(1);
queue.offer(2);
queue.offer(3);
//...

Integer val = null;
while( (val = queue.poll()) != null) {
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

The `Collections.reverseOrder()` provides a `Comparator` that would sort the elements in the `PriorityQueue` in a the oposite order to their natural order in this case.

Comment: `Collections.reverseOrder()` is also overloaded to take a comparator, so it also works if you compare custom objects.

Comment: Java 8's PriorityQueue has a new constructor, which just takes comparator as an argument `PriorityQueue(Comparator<? super E> comparator)`.

Answer (score 114):

You can use lambda expression since Java 8.

The following code will print 10, the larger.

```
// There is overflow problem when using simple lambda as comparator, as pointed out by Фима Гирин.
// PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((x, y) -> y - x);

PriorityQueue<Integer> pq =new PriorityQueue<>((x, y) -> Integer.compare(y, x));

pq.add(10);
pq.add(5);
System.out.println(pq.peek());
```

The lambda function will take two Integers as input parameters, subtract them from each other, and return the arithmetic result. The lambda function implements the Functional Interface, `Comparator<T>`. (This is used in place, as opposed to an anonymous class or a discrete implementation.)

Comment: lambda function, names its input parameters x and y and returns y-x, which is basically what the int comparator class does except it returns x-y

Comment: The comparator like `(x, y) -> y - x` may be not appropriate for long integers due to overflow. For example, numbers y = Integer.MIN_VALUE and x = 5 results in positive number.

It is better to use  `new PriorityQueue<>((x, y) -> Integer.compare(y, x))`.
Though, the better solution is given by @Edwin Dalorzo to use `Collections.reverseOrder()`.

Comment: @ФимаГирин That's true. -2147483648 - 1 becomes 2147483647

Answer (score 65):

In Java 8+ you can create a max priority queue via one of these methods:

Method 1:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> maxPQ = new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Method 2:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> maxPQ = new PriorityQueue<>((a,b) -> b - a);
```

Method 3:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> maxPQ = new PriorityQueue<>((a,b) -> b.compareTo(a));
```

Comment: Be careful on 2nd method, unless there is some constraints on the Integer numbers, it is best to stay away from this method.  Try and  what happened when you insert -2147483648 and 1 to the queue. It will make -2147483648 as the root as supposed to 1.

Comment: Another option for comparator `(u, v) -> Integer.compare(v, u)`.

Answer (score 33):

You can provide a custom `Comparator` object that ranks elements in the reverse order:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(defaultSize, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    public int compare(Integer lhs, Integer rhs) {
        if (lhs < rhs) return +1;
        if (lhs.equals(rhs)) return 0;
        return -1;
    }
});
```

Now, the priority queue will reverse all its comparisons, so you will get the maximum element rather than the minimum element.

Hope this helps!

Comment: maybe for a max priority q the lhs<rhs returs +1;    what you wrote here is minimum q  after my testing

Comment: For reverse printing, that is if the highest elements are to be printed first in a priority queue, it should be `if (rhs < lhs) return +1;` `if (rhs > lhs) return -1;`

Comment: @Diksha I believe the code I have is equivalent to what you're posting. I've just used the greater-than relation rather than less-than.

Comment: actually, my mistake.. I meant it should be like this: `if (lhs < rhs) return +1; if (lhs > rhs) return -1;`

Comment: I had to use `public int compare(Integer lhs, Integer rhs) ` in order get rid of the error message `"cannot implement compare(T,T) in Comparator"`

Comment: @ShrikantPrabhu Good catch - that's now fixed!

Comment: Just `return rhs - lhs` should do.

Comment: @CharlesC I think (?) that you need to watch out for integer overflow with that approach in some cases. But perhaps I’m mistaken?

Comment: @templatetypedef good point, as I saw you explicit passed <Integer> as the type, I assumed that should not happen in the change I suggested.

Answer (score 16):

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer> (
  new Comparator<Integer> () {
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
       return b - a;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: This is perfect and does exactly what was asked by turning a min heap into a max heap.

Comment: using `b-a` can cause `overflow` so should avoid using it and should use `Collections.reverseOrder();` as a comparator or replace b-a with `Integer.compare(a,b);` which has been added in `Java 8`

Answer (score 9):

The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction time.

The Comparator should override the compare method.

```
int compare(T o1, T o2)
```

Default compare method returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

The Default PriorityQueue provided by Java is Min-Heap, If you want a max heap following is the code

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PriorityQueue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(new Comparator<Integer>() {

            public int compare(Integer lhs, Integer rhs) {
                if(lhs<rhs) return +1;
                if(lhs>rhs) return -1;
                return 0;
            }
        });
        q.add(13);
        q.add(4);q.add(14);q.add(-4);q.add(1);
        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(q.poll());
        }
    }

}
```

Reference :https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#comparator()

Answer (score 8):

We can do this by creating our **CustomComparator** class that implements Comparator interface and overriding its compare method. Below is the code for the same :

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Comparator;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PriorityQueue<Integer> nums = new PriorityQueue<>(new CustomComparator());
        nums.offer(21);
        nums.offer(1);
        nums.offer(8);
        nums.offer(2);
        nums.offer(-4);
        System.out.println(nums.peek());
    }
}
class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Integer>{
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer n1, Integer n2){
        int val = n1.compareTo(n2);
        if(val > 0)
           return -1;
        else if(val < 0)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably would be easier just returning `n1.compareTo(n2) * (-1)` or `n2.compareTo(n1)` in `compare` method

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved by the below code in Java 8 which has introduced a constructor which only takes a comparator.

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> maxPriorityQ = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved by using

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a sample Max-Heap in Java :

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq1= new PriorityQueue<Integer>(10, new Comparator<Integer>() {
public int compare(Integer x, Integer y) {
if (x < y) return 1;
if (x > y) return -1;
return 0;
}
});
pq1.add(5);
pq1.add(10);
pq1.add(-1);
System.out.println("Peek: "+pq1.peek());
```

The output will be 10

Answer (score 4):

Change PriorityQueue to MAX PriorityQueue
Method 1 : Queue pq = new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
Method 2 : Queue pq1 = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> b - a);
Let's look at few Examples:

```
public class Example1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(222, 555, 666, 333, 111, 888, 777, 444);
        Queue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
        pq.addAll(ints);
        System.out.println("Priority Queue => " + pq);
        System.out.println("Max element in the list => " + pq.peek());
        System.out.println("......................");
        // another way
        Queue<Integer> pq1 = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> b - a);
        pq1.addAll(ints);
        System.out.println("Priority Queue => " + pq1);
        System.out.println("Max element in the list => " + pq1.peek());
        /* OUTPUT
          Priority Queue => [888, 444, 777, 333, 111, 555, 666, 222]
          Max element in the list => 888
          ......................
           Priority Queue => [888, 444, 777, 333, 111, 555, 666, 222]
           Max element in the list => 888

         */


    }
}
```

Let's take a famous interview 
Problem : Kth Largest Element in an Array using PriorityQueue

```
public class KthLargestElement_1{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(222, 555, 666, 333, 111, 888, 777, 444);
        int k = 3;
        Queue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
        pq.addAll(ints);
        System.out.println("Priority Queue => " + pq);
        System.out.println("Max element in the list => " + pq.peek());
        while (--k > 0) {
            pq.poll();
        } // while
        System.out.println("Third largest => " + pq.peek());
/*
 Priority Queue => [888, 444, 777, 333, 111, 555, 666, 222]
Max element in the list => 888
Third largest => 666

 */
    }
}
```

Another way :

```
public class KthLargestElement_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(222, 555, 666, 333, 111, 888, 777, 444);
        int k = 3;

        Queue<Integer> pq1 = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> b - a);
        pq1.addAll(ints);
        System.out.println("Priority Queue => " + pq1);
        System.out.println("Max element in the list => " + pq1.peek());
        while (--k > 0) {
            pq1.poll();
        } // while
        System.out.println("Third largest => " + pq1.peek());
        /*
          Priority Queue => [888, 444, 777, 333, 111, 555, 666, 222] 
          Max element in the list => 888 
          Third largest => 666

         */
    }
}
```

As we can see, both are giving the same result.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `MinMaxPriorityQueue` (it's a part of the Guava library):
[here's the documentation](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MinMaxPriorityQueue.html). Instead of `poll()`, you need to call the `pollLast()` method.

Comment: 404. That’s an error.

The requested URL /git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MinMaxPriorityQueue.html was not found on this server.   Seems like the link is broken, need to get the detailed info next time.

Answer (score 3):

I have mentioned 5 ways to achieve :

1. Using `compareTo()` Method

```
   PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((o1, o2) -> o2.compareTo(o1));
```

2. Using `compare()` Method

```
   PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((x, y) -> Integer.compare(y, x));
```

3. Using Custom `Comparator` Method

```
   PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(new CustomIntegerComparator());

    static class CustomIntegerComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return o1 < o2 ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
```

4. Using `Collection` Method

```
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq= new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

5. Using `Arrow`(`Lambda` expression) Function

```
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq= new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> b - a);
```

6. Using Custom `Comparator` Method (via Difference)

```
   PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<> (new Comparator<Integer> () 
   {
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) 
      {
          return b - a;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I just ran a Monte-Carlo simulation on both comparators on double heap sort min max and they both came to the same result:

These are the max comparators I have used:

(A) Collections built-in comparator

```
 PriorityQueue<Integer> heapLow = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

(B)  Custom comparator

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> heapLow = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
    int compare(Integer lhs, Integer rhs) {
        if (rhs > lhs) return +1;
        if (rhs < lhs) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: For reverse printing, that is if the highest elements are to be printed first in a priority queue, it should be `if (rhs < lhs) return +1;` if (rhs > lhs) return -1;

Comment: You can edit it if you like. I have no time to confirm what you wrote. In my setup what i wrote was correct

Answer (score 2):

Using lamda, just multiple the result with -1 to get max priority queue.

```
PriorityQueue<> q = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(
                       (a,b) ->  -1 * Integer.compare(a, b)
                    );
```

Comment: Or simply `(a,b) -> b - a`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((x, y) -> -1 * Integer.compare(x, y));
```

Which works for any other base comparison function you might have.

Answer (score 1):

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> lowers = new PriorityQueue<>((o1, o2) -> -1 * o1.compareTo(o2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to Reverse PriorityQueue using ***Collections.reverseOrder()*** in java.

-> I have the PriorityQueue:(like:)

```
    PriorityQueue<String> pQueue = new PriorityQueue<>();
    
    pQueue.add("Honda");
    pQueue.add("Passion");
    pQueue.add("Heroni");
    pQueue.add("Ola");
```

-> Create New PriorityQueue for Reverse array Store.

```
  PriorityQueue<String> pRqueue = new 
              PriorityQueue<String>(pQueue.size(), Collections.reverseOrder());
```

-> in the Syntex ***pQueue.size()*** is the array which is already Declared.
so, give here only the size.

-> add elements of old queue into new Queue:

```
  pRqueue.addAll(pQueue);
```

-> and now print the queue. and Output is shown Below:

```
    Queue Element:[ Heroni, Ola, Honda, Passion ]
    Reverese PriorityQueue Element:[ Passion, Ola, Honda, Heroni ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try pushing elements with reverse sign. Eg: To add a=2 & b=5 and then poll b=5.

```
PriorityQueue<Integer>  pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
pq.add(-a);
pq.add(-b);
System.out.print(-pq.poll());
```

Once you poll the head of the queue, reverse the sign for your usage.
This will print 5 (larger element). Can be used in naive implementations. Definitely not a reliable fix. I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the other answers given here. If you want a very simple hack for this, just revert the sign of the number.
Suppose I want to enter 5 and 10 to the queue,

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq= new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
pq.add(-5);
pr.add(-10);
```

Since Priority Queue by default implements min heap in Java you can use this logic to implement max heap.