# PriorityQueue, what am I missing?

Tags: java, priority-queue

I have a comparator class NComparator that compares 2 Node objects and returns either 1, -1, or 0.

I initialized a PriorityQueue with an initial capacity of 100 and that NComparator.

```
    NComparator nc = new NComparator();
    PriorityQueue<Node> pq = new PriorityQueue<Node>(100, nc);
```

I have about 25 Node objects (that can be compared with NComparator), and I added them all to the PriorityQueue Object:

```
  pq.add(new Node("A", 3));
  pq.add(new Node("G", 1));
  pq.add(new Node("B", 10));
  .... etc
```

How can I arrange these node objects in PriorityQueue by the priority returned by the comparator (which only compares pairwise combinations of nodes)? Specifically, I would like to be able to access the two nodes with the least priority in this PriorityQueue. How can I do that?

Comment: This will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003155/change-priorityqueue-to-max-priorityqueue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PriorityQueue` API only supports getting the single node with the least priority, but you could remove that and then query again to get the next lowest element.

Comment: Thanks, I see. I did not also realize that when I do pq.add, PriorityQueue automatically adds them so they are always retained in order. So removing on element will be removing its lowest priority.

Answer (score 0):

If are you sure that your NComparator arranges the Node elements correctly, and the least priorities are at the head of the queue, then you only need to do, *twice*: `pq.poll()` [See the PriorityQueue API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#poll%28%29)

Example:

```
  Node firstLowerNode = pq.poll();
  Node secondLowerNode = pq.poll();
```