# PriorityQueue Sort

Tags: java, sorting, priority-queue

```
public class Flight implements Comparable {
```

....

```
public int compareTo(Object obj){
    Flight f = (Flight) obj;
    Integer i1 = (Integer) f.priority;
    Integer i2 = (Integer) priority;
    if(f == null)
        return 1;
    else 
        return i2.compareTo(i1);
}
```

....

```
public class JavaPriorityFlightQueue {


    public PriorityQueue flights;
```

....

```
public void joinQueue(Flight f){
        flights.add(f);
        Collections.sort(flights);
    }
```

.....

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method sort(List) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (PriorityQueue)

```
at section3.JavaPriorityFlightQueue.joinQueue(JavaPriorityFlightQueue.java:31)
at section3.FlightTest003.main(FlightTest003.java:19)
```

I used the exact same compareTo for a LinkedList and it works, and everything is the same I have not missed something out (I think). I do not understand how it works for LinkedList but not PriorityQueue.

Comment: Pls check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683041/java-how-do-i-use-a-priorityqueue

Comment: The next value from a PriorityQueue is always the lowest. If you constructor the PriorityQueue with the right Comparator you shouldn't need additional sorting.

Answer (score 3):

`Collections.sort(List<E>)` only accepts **List** implementing classes.
**java.util.LinkedList** implemnts **List** inteface, where as **Priorityqueue** doesnt implement List.
Example:

```
PriorityQueue<String> pq = new PriorityQueue<String>();
        Collections.sort(pq);//compiler error here sort expects a List not priorityQueue
```

check [Collections.sort(List)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) signature

one way to sort a priority queue using Sort method is to  convert priorityqueue to Array and use Arrays.sort().

```
Arrays.sort(pq.toArray());
```

or use a constructor of PQ which takes Comparator as an second argument.

[PriorityQueue pq = new PriorityQueue(initialcapacity, Comparator);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue%28int,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

and read about [java.util.Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Comment: I see so I cannot sort a Queue?

Comment: Comparator<? super E> comparator() 
          Returns the comparator used to order the elements in this queue, or null if this queue is sorted according to the natural ordering of its elements.

Comment: This was in the priorityqueue doc, what is this Comparator exactly and what is it/can it be used for?

Comment: Comparator is an interface in java.util package which is used to custom sort. you could also use that constructor of the priority queue to sort it based on the comparator.

Answer (score 0):

`Collections.sort` can only take a list as an argument, which doesn't really make sense as it is in the `Collections` class. Sadly although `PriorityQueue` is a `Collection`, it does not implement `List`.