# According to nature queue in collection always use CompareTo() method to sort element but in below programme it sort only first element why?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] a)     
{       
  Queue queue = new PriorityQueue();
  queue.add(44);
  queue.add(90);
  queue.add(9);
  queue.add(89);
  queue.add(45);
  queue.add(61);
  queue.add(1);
  System.out.println(queue);
}
```

output :- `[1, 45, 9, 90, 89, 61, 44]`

but output must be `[1,9,44,45,61,89,90]`

Answer (score 3):

The elements will be retreived in sort order when you take them from the queue.

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] a)
{
    Queue queue = new PriorityQueue();
    queue.add(44);
    queue.add(90);
    queue.add(9);
    queue.add(89);
    queue.add(45);
    queue.add(61);
    queue.add(1);
    System.out.println(queue.poll());
    System.out.println(queue.poll());
    System.out.println(queue.poll());
    System.out.println(queue.poll());
    System.out.println(queue.poll());
    System.out.println(queue.poll());
    System.out.println(queue.poll());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `toString()` will output in any particular order. `toString()` is implemented using the `AbstractCollection.toString()`, and that uses the collection's iterator. From the [PriorityQueue doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to
>   traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order

Note that [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683041/java-how-do-i-use-a-priorityqueue) may be of further use.

Answer (score 1):

A queue (specifically a priority queue or priority heap) is **not a list**!

It's sorting does **not** mean that every element is sorted (or that you get any specific ordering).

It *only* means that whenever you `poll()` an element, it will be the smallest!

That *could* be achieved by storing a totally sorted list *or* (as it happens to be the case) by using a different, more efficient data structure: [a heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29).

Comment: It looks like this more efficient data structure is a Heap.

Comment: @Dahaka: correct, it's even documented in [the JavaDoc of `PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).