# Java Priority Queue Sorting

Tags: java, priority-queue

I have a `PriorityQueue` called `Incoming`, that contains objects of type `Vehicle`.

You can call the method `getFuelLevel()` on all `Vehicles`.

What I want to do is to sort `Incoming`, so that the `Vehicles` with the least `fuel` are given a higher priority and are put at the front of the Queue.

I'm assuming I have to use a `Comparator` here but have no idea how to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683041/java-how-do-i-use-a-priorityqueue

Comment: Is this `java.util.PriorityQueue` or are you writing your own implementation? If you are writing your own, try using a heap.

Comment: There is a good example at: http://www.journaldev.com/1642/java-priority-queue-priorityqueue-example that demonstrates how to use a comparator in a sort.

Comment: @McLovin this is the util

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that I always do when using a `PriorityQueue` with my own class is to make that class implement `Comparable<Class>`. With this, rather than needing to implement a Comparator, all you need to implement is the `int compareTo(Class o)` method in the class which returns "a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object."

In your case, this would return 1 if the `Vehicles` has less fuel than the `Vehicles` inputed, 0 if the two have the same, and -1 if the `Vehicles` has more fuel than the one inputed.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Answer (score 1):

The `PriorityQueue` class has a constructor that takes a `Comparator` as an argument. You can construct a `PriorityQueue` by providing your specific `Comparator` as

```
PriorityQueue<Vehicle> queue = new PriorityQueue<Vehicle>(initialCapacity, new Comparator<Vehicle> {
    int compare(Vehicle a, Vehicle b) {
        return a.getFuelLevel() - b.getFuelLevel();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you take a look at my use of a PriorityQueue in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800287/how-to-restore-the-priorityqueue-to-its-initial-state-before-the-method-call?noredirect=1#comment45875800_28800287