# priority queue in C++ to java

Tags: java, c++, priority-queue

could anyone please tell me how to write this priority queue (written in C++) using Java

```
priority_queue< pair< int, Hole >, vector< pair< int, Hole > >, Hole::CompH > moves;
```

the CompH is a struct:

```
   struct CompH {
                bool operator()(const pair< int, Hole >& lhs, const pair< int, Hole >& rhs) const
                {
                        return lhs.second.getH() < rhs.second.getH();
                }
        };
```

I want to understand this part so I can write it in Java, Please. 
Thanks

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683041/java-how-do-i-use-a-priorityqueue

Comment: Don't use C++ code to figure out how to write Java code.  The same thing can be said about using Java code to figure out how to write C++ code  -- don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

The CompH is directly analogous to a java.util.Comparator, and the PQ class itself is java.util.PriorityQueue.