# How to add an element in front of Queue in java?

Tags: java, queue, reverse, deque

I am using `Queue<T> q1` and I know that an element will be added using `q1.offer();` at the end of the queue. But now, what I want to do is add an element in front of queue, which is not possible with Queue. The possible methods I could think of are

- Use of double ended queue and I can add the elements in front and at the end.
- reverse the q1, add the element at the end of the queue and reverse again.

Now, as a non-programmer guy, I am not sure, how to code these methods; which one is more economical and easier to do.

Problems I faced in 1) is transform of existing Queue to Deque and vice versa; and in 2) How to use `Collections.reverseOrder();` to reverse the existing Queue.

Comment: If your requirements are satisfied by data structure X, why the heck use data structure Y?

Comment: You could use priority Queue.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683041/java-how-do-i-use-a-priorityqueue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following is the way to add elements to the  first of queue using deque and asLifoQueue method in collections.this will arrange the elements in last in first out order...

```
    public class Practice15 {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Deque<Integer> dd=new ArrayDeque<Integer>();

    dd.offerFirst(123);

    dd.offerFirst(258);

    dd.offerFirst(125);

    System.out.println(dd);

    Queue<Integer> q1=Collections.asLifoQueue(dd);

    System.out.println(q1);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you have to insert an element at the front, a [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) is definitely not the solution. Go for a [`double ended queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you use "Queue q1" - that is only a declaration of variable *q1*, while *Queue* itself is only an interface. Are you probably looking to work with some implementation of Queue?

Check out Java API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)