# Add Key and Value into an Priority Queue and Sort by Key in Java

Tags: java, priority-queue

I am trying to take in a List of strings and add them into a Priority Queue with Key and Value. The Key being the word and the value being the string value of the word. Then I need to sort the queue with the highest string value first. The priority queue is not letting me add 2 values.

```
public static List<String> pQSortStrings(List<String> strings) {
    PriorityQueue<String, Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<>();

    for (int x = 0; x < strings.size(); x++) {
        q.add(strings.get(x),calculateStringValue(strings.get(x)));
    }
    return strings;
}
```

Comment: > "The key being the word and the value being the string of the word"
The words are strings? its not clear what you are doing or why you are doing it

Comment: You're not using the PQ correctly. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/683041/268093) for a proper example.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Problem

[`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) can store a single object in it's each node. So what you are trying to do can not be done as it is.

But you can compose both objects in a single class and then use the `PriorityQueue`.

You would either need to supply a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) or rely on [natural ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) by implementing [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.

---

### Solution

- Create a class which has `String` and `int` as it's members.

  ```
  public class Entry {
      private String key;
      private int value;

      // Constructors, getters etc.
  }
  ```
- Implement `Comparable` interface and delegate comparison to `String`.

  ```
  public class Entry implements Comparable<Entry> {
      private String key;
      private int value;

      public Entry(String key, int value) {
          this.key = key;
          this.value = value;
      }

      // getters

      @Override
      public int compareTo(Entry other) {
          return this.getKey().compareTo(other.getKey());
      }
  }
  ```
- Build the `PriorityQueue` using this class.

  ```
  PriorityQueue<Entry> q = new PriorityQueue<>();
  ```
- Add elements as following.

  ```
  q.add(new Entry(strings.get(x), calculateStringValue(strings.get(x))));
  ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Now after Java-8 we could use the Entry class provided by java to do the same operations. That is much more consistent and reliable.

Answer (score 21):

Using Java-8

```java
PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()));
```

to add a new Entry

```java
queue.offer(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("A", 10));
```

Comment: please explain the queue argument

Comment: i believe that the constructor arg is the comparator.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

```
public static List<String> pQSortStrings(List<String> strings) {    
    Queue<String> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> 
        calculateStringValue(b) - calculateStringValue(a));
    for (String str : strings) {
         pq.add(str);
    }
    return strings;
}
```

### Explanation

I believe that the cleanest way to do this is to store Strings in your pq and use a small custom `Comparator`.
In this case, we want to use `calculateStringValue` and the pq should return highest `String` values first. Therefore, make a pq of entries and use the following `Comparator`:

```
1   Queue<String> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<String>() {
2       @Override
3       public int compare(String a, String b) {
4           return calculateStringValue(b) - calculateStringValue(a);
5       }
6   });
7   for (String str : strings) {
8       pq.add(str);
9   }
10  return strings;
```

Simpler syntax for the `Comparator`, replacing lines 1 - 6, is:

```
Queue<String> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> 
    calculateStringValue(b) - calculateStringValue(a));
```

If you wanted to return smallest `String` values first, you could just switch the order around for `a` and `b` in the `Comparator`:

```
...new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> calculateStringValue(a) - calculateStringValue(b));
```

In general, the pattern `a - b` sorts by smallest first, and `b - a` sorts by largest values first.

Answer (score 1):

Many good answers are already present but I am posting this answer because no one has used hashmap in their answers.

---

You can also make the priority Queue from HashMaps bellow is the example for the same. I am creating a max priority queue.
**Mind well here I am considering that your hashmap contains only one Entry**

```
PriorityQueue<HashMap<Character, Integer>> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> {
        char keyInA = a.keySet().iterator().next(); // key of a
        char keyInB = b.keySet().iterator().next(); // key of b
        return b.get(keyInB) - a.get(keyInA);
    });
```

For Insertion of the value in the priority queue.

```
pq.add(new HashMap<>() {
            {
                put('a', 0);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a class with a key field and a value field

```
Class MyClass{
    int key;
    String value
}

Queue<MyClass> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparotor.comparingInt(a -> a.key));
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Tanmay Patil Answer, If you are using Java 8, You can use lambda for more concise code as comparator interface is a functional interface.

```
public class CustomEntry {
    private String key;
    private int value;

    public CustomEntry(String key, int value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    // getters etc.
}
```

Now below is the updated code

```
public static List<String> pQSortStrings(List<String> strings) {
    PriorityQueue<CustomEntry> q = new PriorityQueue<>((x, y) -> {
        // since you want to sort by highest value first
        return Integer.compare(y.getValue(), x.getValue()); 
    });

    for (int x = 0; x < strings.size(); x++) {
        q.add(new CustomEntry(strings.get(x),calculateStringValue(strings.get(x))));
    }
    return strings;
}
```

To use this priority queue

```
CustomEntry topEntry = q.peek();
System.out.println("key : " + topEntry.getKey());
System.out.println("value : " + topEntry.getValue());
```

Same logic can be also be applied by using `Map.Entry<String, Integer>`  provided by java for storing key, pair value