# Sorting Values based on ArrayList of Objects

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist

I stuck with comparing values. Array List consists of two objects Name and Percentage.

```
public class DataModel {

    private String name;
    private String dataUsagePercent;
     int color;
}
```

and array list is

```
 List<DataModel> usageList;


 Collections.sort(usageList, new Comparator<DataModel>(){
        public int compare(DataModel d1, DataModel d2){

            return (d1.getDataUsagePercent()) - Integer.parseInt(d2.getDataUsagePercent()));
        }

    });
```

Example :

dataUsagePercent values in a arraylist is `2, 10, 40, 30, 50, 60, 90, 65,55,100.`

i have to compare the values of `dataUsagePercent`. lowest should come at 0th position in arraylist and  the top four categories
that make up the highest value of dataUsagePercent. Additionally, the six remaining values (that make up the lowest percentage of usage)
are combined into a single percentage.

Output for above values after comparing list should consists of  :

```
2,10+30+40+50+55+60,65,90,100 means 2, 245,65,90,100
```

final list size should be always 5 only and name value has no impact

Edit: Missed 60. add to combined value

Comment: You could create another ArrayList and put a copy of all the percentages in it, then use `Collections.sort(arraylist)`. Then grab four highest and the lowest value, and add the rest. This is assuming the name has no impact on the percentages.

Comment: You would need to implement Comparable to use Collections.sort

Comment: [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-)?

Comment: Where's the value `60`? It's neither in the final list as a direct value, nor summed to form the 5th value.

Comment: missed it, added now

Answer (score 0):

I think your list data type need to change as `List<DataUsageModel> usageList;`
to compare dataUsagePercent values you can use `Collections.sort(usageList);`
or you can use [priority queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683041/how-do-i-use-a-priorityqueue)

Answer (score 0):

First, order the list by `dataUsagePercent`:

```
usageList.sort(
    Comparator.comparing(
        DataModel::getDataUsagePercent, 
        Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::parseInt)));
```

Here I'm using [`List.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) and [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-) methods.

Then, I'd use a common for loop to do the grouping, taking care of the index:

```
int[] topFive = new int[5];

int size = usageList.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    int value = Integer.parseInt(usageList.get(i).getDataUsagePercent());
    if (i == 0) {
        topFive[0] = value; // lowest value at the beginning
    } else if (i > 0 && i < size - 3) {
        topFive[1] += value; // accumulate intermediate values in 2nd position
    } else {
        topFive[i - size + 5] = value; // top values in the last 3 positions
    }
}
```

The output is `[2, 245, 65, 90, 100]`.

Answer (score 0):

First I would sort the list:

```
Collections.sort(usageList, new Comparator<DataModel>(){
    public int compare(DataModel d1, DataModel d2){
        return Integer.compare(d1.getDataUsagePercent(), d2.getDataUsagePercent());
    }
});
```

- After that you can just take the first element and the last 3.
- Add the middle values together
- And create your result array