# I've got 3 strings that each have a different value, I need to rank them from most value to least. How?

Tags: java

I was thinking maybe HashMap, but that doesn't allow sorting. Maybe list? I honestly have no clue. I've been struggling with this a lot.

Strings: "Tom", "Sarah", "Oliver". 
Values: 323, 237.2, 12.1

Comment: What correlation, if any, exists between your data sets?

Comment: How do you know which value corresponds to which string?  Hint: perhaps you should create a class that holds a string and its "value".  You could even make that class comparable...

Comment: Once you have class that holds a name and value, one option is to use [Collections.sort( List<T>, Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator), with a Comparable that you implement to consider the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use entries with Key and Value like you would do in a hash table but add that entries to a Priority Queue that must be created with the comparator you want.

**Here is an example:**  [How do I use a PriorityQueue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683041/how-do-i-use-a-priorityqueue)

In that case the comparator is created to compare string lengths but you can change that to compare the value of an entry.

The difference is that you have to create the PriorityQueue as new PriorityQueue> instead of new PriorityQueue

Hopes it helps

Comment: I don't know how to do this