# compareTo in Java Priority Queue working erratic

Tags: java

The compareTo function that I am using in my class

```
public int compareTo(Book b) {  
    if(id>b.id){  
        return 1;  
    }else if(id<b.id){  
        return -1;  
    }else{  
    return 0;  
    }

}
```

When I add a priorityQueue, with ids in the order 12 99 89 55 40 4, the output I get is:

```
4
40
12
99
55
89
```

The code which I use to iterate the PriorityQueue is:

```
Iterator it = queue.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
  Book b = (Book)it.next();
  System.out.println(b.id);
}
```

What could be the problem for such output?
    Once I invoke queue.remove() and then iterate, the order seems correct.

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683041/how-do-i-use-a-priorityqueue

Comment: ty for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iterator of a `PriorityQueue` is not guaranteed to return the elements in the order defined by the `Comparable` implementation of your element class (`Book`).

From the Javadoc of `PriorityQueue`:

> This class and its iterator implement all of the optional methods of the Collection and Iterator interfaces. **The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order**. If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).