# Add element with specified priority

Tags: data-structures, queue, priority-queue

I need a data structure like a Priority Queue that allows me to enter an element 
by specifying a priority value.
(Ex: queue.add( "Element", 12); where 12 is the priority of value.

If doesn't exist a similar method, can you suggest me the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: why not use arrays? array[priority] = value

Comment: The Number of priorities is undefined.

Comment: Use ArrayList or Stack ?

Comment: No, because when I insert a new Element, It should sort the date Structure according a value specified by me and not according the Element's Comparator

Comment: Use priority queue with the overridden comparator to fit your needs

Comment: If I use a Comparator, I Need to create an Object that  pairs <Element,Value> and then I create a Queue of this Object. Is this the most efficient way?

Comment: In my opinion, it is

Comment: An insert operation is a pretty fundamental part of what a priority queue is, and every element needs to have a priority anyway, so what's the problem here? Just do a normal insert? If you're having trouble doing this in some given language, you should post your code in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: @Dukeling How can I tell to  my Queue how to sort my elements? Is there a solution without using Comparator or the best solution is that suggested by Anand ?

Comment: If this is Java (which I'm just guessing here), see [How do I use a PriorityQueue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683041/how-do-i-use-a-priorityqueue) Comparator and Comparable are your only options.