# How do i dequeue from an array list of objects that have multiple parameters?

Tags: java, queue, priority-queue

I am trying to dequeue based off the integer value in my priority queue, rather than the name (String) value. For instance, [Sally, 4] should be pulled before [John, 1]. Because 4 is higher in priority than 1. However the way I have structured my Queue, it is polling by alphabet from the first variable (name). Any step in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
package stackqueuewood;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StackQueueWood {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> people = new ArrayList<>();

        people.add(person("Tom", 3));
        people.add(person("Dick", 4));   
        people.add(person("Harry", 2));                 

    PriorityQueue<String> pQ = new PriorityQueue<>();

        pQ.addAll(people);
        System.out.println("The current queue size is: " + pQ.size());
        System.out.println("The current queue is: \n" + pQ);

        System.out.println(pQ.peek());
        pQ.poll();
        System.out.println(pQ);
}
public static String person(String name, int priority){

    return ("(" + name + ", " + priority + ")");
 }  
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use a PriorityQueue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683041/how-do-i-use-a-priorityqueue)

Comment: So where in that does it explain what I am asking, because I cannot find it sadly. Those show single parameter objects.

Comment: You'll have to actually create a class to model the `person`. Then the approach should be much the same

Comment: So the method person should be removed, and a separate class created that does the same thing correct? that way the class works as a constructor that can be manipulated? where as the method I have cannot be manipulated?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than concatenating the two values together into a `String`, create a new class to represent a person, with fields for name and priority. Then you can use a `PriorityQueue<Person>` and specify the `Comparator` to use (probably `Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getPriority)`).

Comment: Ahhh, okay. I see what you are saying, ill give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
Comparator<String> orderIsdn =  new Comparator<String>() { 
    //Your sorting method
}
```

then:

```
PriorityQueue<String> pQ = new PriorityQueue<>(orderIsdn);
```

Comment: Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Use `code blocking` for code and log and error texts and **bold** and *italics* to highlight things. also elaborate your answer.