# JAVA PriorityQueue comparator not accepting float

Tags: java, comparator

### I have the following class:

```
    int x;
    int y;
    float distance;

    public Point(int x, int y, float distance){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.distance = distance;
    }
}
```

---

### On my main program I have this line:

```
PriorityQueue<Point> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<Point>( (a,b) -> ((float) a.distance - (float) b.distance) );
```

---

### I keep getting this error:

````
        PriorityQueue<Point> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<Point>( (a,b) -> ((float) a.distance - (float) b.distance) );
                                                                                              ^
    possible lossy conversion from float to int```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I dont know why is not accepting my comparator method. Any ideas? thanks in advance.
````

Comment: The `compare()` method from the `Comparator` you provide must return an `int`, not a `float`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683041/how-do-i-use-a-priorityqueue . Check this for reference .

Answer (score 4):

That's because the `compare` method you're defining returns an `int`, but since you're getting an `int` with an operation between `float`s the compiler tells you some data might get lost (it actually will, all the decimals, but you don't really care since it's just a comparator).

You could use [`Float.compare(f1, f2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#compare(float,%20float)) in

```
PriorityQueue<Point> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<Point>( (a,b) -> Float.compare(a.distance, b.distance));
```

Comment: Thinking again about it, you *do* care about the decimals. If you compare `10.1` with `10.9` and return an `int`, you'll get `0` and the comparator will treat the numbers as equal, but they're not. You're welcome ^^