# Java Priority Queue with ArrayLists and Pairs

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, priority-queue

I'm looking for simple way to build a Priority Queue in Java. I've built an `ArrayList<Pair>`, and each `Pair` instance contains an `X` and `Y` values.

```java
class Pair {
    private final Float xVal;
    private final Float yVal;

    public Pair(Float aXVal, Float aYVal) {
        xVal = aXVal;
        yVal = aYVal;
    }

    public float getX() {
        return xVal;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return yVal;
    }
}
```

My `ArrayList` looks like:

```
ArrayList<Pair> listOfPoints;
```

Using the `ArrayList listOfPoints`, I wanted to build two priority queues:

- One that is sorted on the x Values from low to high.
- One that is sorted on the y Values form low to high.

I was looking for a simple way to do this using Lambda expressions.

I did look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683041/how-do-i-use-a-priorityqueue) question on Stack Overflow, and I found this code:

```
PriorityQueue<String> pq=
                    new PriorityQueue<String>(5,(a,b) -> a.length() - b.length());
```

I think this is close to what I want.

I was trying to implement the following:

```
PriorityQueue<Pair> xSorted = new PriorityQueue<Pair>(numOfPoints, (x1,x2) -> Need Help Here);
```

How do I access Pair in order to have it compare `x1` and `x2`?

Note, that `nummberOfPoints` I was setting to the length of `ArrayList<Pair> listOfPoints`.

Comment: Hi I provided that link as a reference the code block right below it is what I found helpful in that link. 
What i want is a lambada expression to use in the priorirty queue knowing that I'm using the class <Pair> instead of <String>

Comment: `PntPair` constructor does not compile for the `Pair` class. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64306525/edit) your question and format it as well.

Comment: Your array list should be `List<Pair> listOfPoints`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the natural (*ascending*) order based on `xVal`:

```java
PriorityQueue<Pair> pq= new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingDouble(Pair::getX));
```

For the reversed (*descending*) order based on `xVal`:

```java
PriorityQueue<Pair> pq= new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingDouble(Pair::getX).reversed());
```

You can use the same approach for `yVal` or any other *comparable* field, by using [Comparator API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html).

Comment: Understood how to use it on <Strings> was unsure how to use lambada expressions on my class <Pair>. I'd like to access Pair X1 and Pair X2 and have the priority queue be sorted on the smallest value of X from that comparison.

Comment: Awesome thank you! I'll give that a shot. Can Comparator run on float values?

Comment: See the Comparator API link provided in the answer. There are different *comparingX* methods, so, yes, it can compare floats.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use lambda like this if you don't want Pair class to implement Comparator interface

```java
PriorityQueue<Pair> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(5, (p1, p2) -> Float.compare(p1.getX(), p2.getX()));
```

For reverse order:

```java
PriorityQueue<Pair> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(5, (p1, p2) -> Float.compare(p2.getX(), p1.getX()));
```

If you prefer your comparison logic in a static factory method or utility function, you can use something like this:

```java
PriorityQueue<Pair> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(NodeUtil::customCompare);

public static int customCompare(Pair p1, Pair p2) {
  return Float.compare(p1.getX(), p2.getX());
}
```