# AnyLogic: How customers choose smallest queue?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

If we have 2 queues, we can simply use SelectOutPut, `if (queue1.size() < queue2.size())` go to Queue1, else go to Queue2.

**But what if we have 12 queues?**
Using only if else will be a nightmare. So what will be our approach?

Note:
Going through all the queues through a for loop could be the answer. If it's possible, then how?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the purpose of the conditions when you need smaller size or bigger and etc.

You can probably use a `PriorityQueue` the complexity will be bigger but it will looks cleaner in the code.

[How do I use a PriorityQueue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683041/how-do-i-use-a-priorityqueue)

each time you poll from the PQ you can choose whether the smaller will be first or the bigger ( in size I assume ) and you insert in right after - so it can be used after (if needed).

if you are still want to do this with a loop - please give more details on what you trying to achieve, since its kinda hard to guess

Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

you can add all the queues into a collection and then do this

```
Queue queue=top(collection,q->-q.size());
go to queue
```

Comment: I made the collection of queues. Now, the code you write, what it is doing and where I should paste it, can you explain it? With source, we can attach only one queue, so how to solve that problem?